# Make an array of multiple Xpath queries

Tags: php, xpath

I have seen that it is possible to make an array from two xpath queries, like this [one](http://www.itsalif.info/content/php-domxpath-read-complex-xml-files-easily):

```
// initialize and the file into load DomDocument
$youTubeDom = new DomDocument();
$youTubeDom->load('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/recently_featured');

// intialize an DomXPath object
$xPath      = new DomXPath($youTubeDom);

// register the namespace on YouTube (its declared on feed element)
$xPath->registerNamespace('yte', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

// now run the 2 queries, add the suffix of that namespace because feed, entry etc. belong to that namespace
$linkNodes  = $xPath->query("/yte:feed/yte:entry/yte:link[@type='text/html']");
$titleNodes     = $xPath->query("/yte:feed/yte:entry/yte:title[@type='text']");


$recentList = array();
for($i=0;$i<$titleNodes->length;$i++) {
    $recentList[$i] = array(
        'title' => $titleNodes->item($i)->nodeValue ,
        'url'   => $linkNodes->item($i)->getAttribute('href')
    );

}
```

And as result from the above example, the array would look like:

```
array(25) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(52) "YouTube Symphony Orchestra @ Carnegie Hall - Act One"
    ["url"]=>
    string(42) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueJcRmfweSM"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(38) ""The Internet Symphony" Global Mash Up"
    ["url"]=>
    string(42) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC4FAyg64OI"
  }
```

But how about a query that has more then two, in my case six queries? Either as a multiple query, divided with `|`:

```
$data = $xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_salong')] | 
//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_time')] | 
//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_versions')]/div[contains(@class, 'mv_3d')] | 
//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_versions')]/div[contains(@class, 'mv_txt')] | 
//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_rs')] | 
//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_btn')]/a[contains(@class, 'smallYellowBtn smallBtn')]/@href");
```

Or divided like the following:

```
$title = $xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_salong')]");
$time = $xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_time')]");
$threed = $xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_versions')]/div[contains(@class, 'mv_3d')]");
$textad = $xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_versions')]/div[contains(@class, 'mv_txt')]");
$freeseats = $xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_rs')]");
$href = $xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'selectShowRow')]/div[contains(@class, 'cmil_btn')]/a[contains(@class, 'smallYellowBtn smallBtn')]/@href");
```

A simple solution, not so great, would be to iterate over each result and then merge the arrays into one. But this will probably mix the results, if a query returs `empty/NULL`.

A good end result would be:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [movie] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Example ONE
                    [time] => 11:30
                    [threed] => 0
                    [textad] => 1
                    [freeseats] => 244
                    [href] => http://example.com/1
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Example Two
                    [time] => 21:00
                    [threed] => 1
                    [textad] => 1
                    [freeseats] => 100
                    [href] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

## **My question:**

1. How do I add result from multiple Xpath query into stdClass?

Comment: Your 6-way Xpath queries seem to be looking at a completely different XML schema as the first examples. Could you provide an example XML, so we have something to play with?

Comment: The first query was from a youtube rss example, the second six query is for a HTML page.

Comment: That YouTube example works only because there is always a 1:1 relationship with the results from the 2 queries. But when there isn't, its a bad model to follow.
In my opinion, you would be better off thinking about it differently, so that your results are more structured. For example, find the theatres first.  Iterate through them, finding the shows that relate to each specific theatre. Then go through those and get the details for each specific show etc. That way, it won't matter if some information is missing for a particular show, because you have a context to work from.

Comment: Please provide example XML or HTML.

Comment: @KeithHall Thanks for you comment. I have been looking at another answer you gave me, and i have been googling to try to do what you say. But unfortunately I cannot, what do you suggest I do?